# A question about the condition of Cauchy's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Theorem 10.12 from Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis says:

Suppose $F \in H(\Omega),F'$ is continuous in $\Omega$ .Then for every closed path $\gamma$ in $\Omega$ ,$\int_{\gamma}F'(z)dz=0$.

And a path is defined to be a piecewise continuously differentiable curve in the plane.

The key point of the proof is to use the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$\int_\gamma F'(z)dz:=\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} F'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt\color{red}{=} F(\gamma(\beta))-F(\gamma(\alpha))=0$ .

**Question:**

Since $\gamma$ is piecewise continuously differentiable,then $F'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)$ is not continuous on some points in $[\alpha,\beta]$. $F'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)$ could have no primitive functions and we cannot use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

So I think maybe **closed path $\gamma$** should be revised as **closed path $\gamma$ which is continuously differentiable**?

Comment: Just compute $\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} F'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$ as a sum of integrals over the intervals $[t_{k-1}, t_k]$ on which $\gamma$ is differentiable.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for that.i've trapped myself in because theorem 10.13 is about integral on a triangle(and some effort is made to prove it),and i mistakenly think that it's a special case of theorem 10.12...

Comment: By definition $\alpha,\beta)$ is the union of finitely many intervals $I$ such that $\gamma'$ is continuous on the interior of $I$. Apply FTC on each $I$ and add.